# How to access appium and stf from other remote machine

Tags: java, appium

I installed stf and appium in linux-1 machine with devices connected and my test scripts are in linux-2 machine and i am trying to execute my script from linux-2 machine. Can i know how to switch on the appium server of linux-1 machine from linux 2 machine through java